# How to add text AFTER inputs in Django forms

Tags: python, django

I have a form which ideally would render like this:

```
<label>Price: </label>
<input type="number" />USD
```

Visually it would be

```
Price: |___________| USD
```

I know that the `label` attribute of a form field can add text BEFORE an input, but I want to know if it's possible to add text AFTER an input.

(1) I understand if I iterate over fields in the template, I would be able to achieve this with something like

```
{{ field }}
{% if field.name == "price" %}
&nbsp;USD
{% endif %}
```

However I do not want to go this route if possible.

(2) I already tried `help_text`, but it adds an extra `<br />` tag between the input and the help text, and it does not render what I want.

```
<label>Price: </label>
<input type="number" />
<br />
<span>USD</span>
```

```
Price: |___________|
USD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Django forms does not provide any way I think to do what you want to do with automatically form templating.

You have to iterate as you said, over all fields. You can create a custom field for managing price field and check the type of you field in your custom form template for adding USD, EUR...etc

Documentation provides some information about reusable form templating here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates